# HTML Form Not Displaying Correct Data in Handlebars View

Tags: javascript, html, css, handlebars.js, joi

I'm working with handlebars for the first time while creating an express app with sequelize and postgresql (courtesy of brad traversy). Upon filling out a form, I am using Joi for validating the request body , if there is an error I re-render the form (view) keeping the originally entered values. The problem is when this happens the text is being trimmed automatically.

E.G. I fill out the title field with "Hello World" and don't fill another field in the form, Joi won't be happy so I re-render the form (view) and when the title repopulates in the form, it will just say "Hello" instead.

***Post Endpoint for Gig Resource***

```
// Add a Gig
router.post("/add", (req, res) => {
    let { title, technologies, budget, description, contact_email } = req.body;

    const { error } = validateGig(req.body);

    if (error) {
        // Re-Render The Form
        return res.status(400).render("add", {
            error: error.details[0].message,
            title,
            technologies,
            budget,
            description,
            contact_email
        });
    } else {
        budget == "" ? (budget = "Unknown") : (budget = `$${budget}`);

        // Make Lower Case and Remove Space After Comma
        technologies = technologies.toLowerCase().replace(/, /g, ",");

        // Insert Into Table
        Gig.create({
            title,
            technologies,
            budget,
            description,
            contact_email
        })
            .then((gig) => res.redirect("/gigs"))
            .catch((err) => console.log("Error Adding Gig" + err));
    }
});
```

***Handlebars View***

```
<section id="add" class="container">
    <div class="form-wrap">
        <h1>Add A Gig</h1>
        <p>Your contact email will be shared with registered users to apply to your gig</p>
        {{#if error}}
        <div class="error">
            <p>{{error}}</p>
        </div>
        {{/if}}
        <form action="/gigs/add" method="POST">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="title">Gig Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="input-box"
                    placeholder="eg. Small Wordpress website, React developer" maxlength="100" value={{title}}>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="technologies">Technologies Needed</label>
                <input type="text" name="technologies" id="technologies" class="input-box"
                    placeholder="eg. javascript, react, PHP" maxlength="100" value={{technologies}}>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="budget">Budget (Leave blank for unknown)</label>
                <input type="number" name="budget" id="budget" class="input-box" placeholder="eg. 500, 5000, 10000"
                    value={{budget}}>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="description">Gig Description</label>
                <textarea name="description" id="description" class="input-box"
                    placeholder="Describe the details of the gig" rows="10">{{description}}</textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="budget">Contact Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="contact_email" id="contactemail" class="input-box"
                    placeholder="Enter an email" value={{contact_email}}>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Add Gig" class="btn btn-reverse">
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using variables in your template, you'll still want to include the quotes around the attribute value.

For example:

```html
value={{title}}
```

Should be written as

```html
value="{{title}}"
```

Comment: Thanks so much again Christopher.